# Highcharts with Firebase

Tags: firebase, highcharts, firebase-realtime-database

I'm looking to graph some data with highcharts pulling the data from firebase - But I have no idea how. I have no experience or knowledge with highcharts and I am not sure where to start.

I have looked through the internet and as of yet have not had any luck finding anything useful. The only promising example I have found, as mentioned in a previous question, was here:

http://blog.dotnetnerd.dk/post/2014/01/27/Realtime-data-displays-with-Firebase.aspx

But this throws an error in my console saying:

```
firebase.js:43 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

My question is - is there anybody in the stack community who has any experience using highcharts and firebase together? If so - Do you understand why the example in the link posted above does not work for me? Does anyone have any other examples of highcharts with firebase which may be of use?

My code so far:

```js
var fbase = new Firebase("https://<MyFirebaseURL>.firebaseio.com/products"); 
    
    fbase.on("value", function(data) { 
        var model = data.val(); 
          $('#container').highcharts({ 
            chart: { type: 'column' }, 
            title: { text: 'Sales' }, 
            xAxis: { 
                categories: model.Categories 
            }, 
            yAxis: { title: { text: 'Quantity' } }, 
            series: model.Series.map(function(element) { 
                return { 
                    name: element.Name, 
                    data: element.Data 
                } 
            })                        
        });                
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js"></script> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script> 

<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
```

And heres the snippet of JSON for the firebase database:

```
    {
  "Categories" : [ "Cat1", "Cat2", "Cat3" ],
  "Series" : {
    "Data" : [ [ 5, 2 ], [ 6, 3 ], [ 8, 2 ] ],
    "Name" : [ "George", "Joe", "Bloggs" ]
  }
}
```

[image]

Apologies if this is a dumb question but I could really use a bit of help.

Thank you in advance,

G

Comment: we use both, together at work; without seeing all of your code, the error isn't 100% clear, but i'm willing to bet you are not pointing to the firebase .json url, and that is what is throwing you off. i have a dummy json project on firebase that i can share with you if getting set up on firebase is problem/issue/you just want to learn...but share all of your code so we can debug it.

Comment: Hi @albert - Thank you for your response. I've added the JS and a snippet of my firebase JSON just to show how its structured so far.

Comment: Would I be able to have a look at that firebase JSON @albert? So that I can check if my data has been entered correctly

Comment: Hi George, 

Could you please check, how your data.val() looks like? is this a JSON object or a string? For now it looks that model.Series may be shown as undefined in your case.

Comment: Hi @GrzegorzBlachliński I've added a screenshot from when I do console.log(model)  where model equals data.val()

Comment: It looks that your data is a single point instead of an array. Highcharts expects data as an array. More information: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series

Comment: So even though i've replaced my data with: data: [[5, 2], [6, 3], [8, 2]] as shown in the link you sent - I still receive the same error

Comment: Looking into your console.log(model) it looks that Series obj is inside Categories obj. Could you please check this issue?

Comment: I have updated the question to include the new formatted firebase database where series is no longer inside categories - but still the error exists

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146430/discussion-between-grzegorz-blachlinski-and-georgebt).